# First Plot misses the Show

Tags: plotting

```
g4 = ContourPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
g5 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
Show[{g4, g5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

How to make the Show include both the Contour plots (but not just the latter)?

Comment: It's there, but since the polygons in `g5` are opaque, you won't be able to see `g4` underneath. Anyway: `Show[{g4, g5 /. p_Polygon :> {Opacity[2/5], p}}]`. (I don't want to post it since it looks too confusing.)

Comment: Try for example `g5 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}] /. 
  x : RGBColor[__] :> Sequence[x, Opacity[.5]]`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Direct DashDot appendage of g5 seems to avoid its echo.  Show[g4, g5 /. x : RGBColor[__] :> Sequence[x, Opacity[.5]]]

Comment: @Guess who it is. Thanks, Shall color g5 to recognize it.